# sorting using vector pair in c++

Tags: c++

I am using vector pair to sort where I am inserting first and second element using a loop

```
vect.push_back(make_pair(count[i],arr[i]));

sort(vect.begin(),vect.end());

cout<<vect[i].second<<" ";
```

if my counts are equal then I want to print the second element in the order they were inserted in vector,

but it is not happening.

Can someome tell me why?

Comment: related: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: After you sort the vector, the original order is not there anymore. So you get the sorted order.

Comment: If equal elements should not be reordered then `std::sort` is the wrong tool for the job. The right tool would be [std::stable_sort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_sort).

Comment: @CoryKramer conveniently ignoring the first part of the question, which is _"if my counts are equal"_

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort)

> Sorts the elements in the range [first, last) in ascending order. *The order of equal elements is not guaranteed to be preserved.*
>   1) Elements are compared using operator<.

and from [`std::pair::operator<`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/operator_cmp)

> 3) If lhs.first < rhs.first, returns true. Otherwise, if rhs.first < lhs.first, returns false. Otherwise, if lhs.second < rhs.second, returns true. Otherwise, returns false.

So effectively, sort compares `count[i]`, and if two of them are equal, it compares `arr[i]`.

---

If you want to compare the `count`s only and keep the original order for equal keys, you must use [`std::stable_sort(first, last, comp)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_sort)

> Sorts the elements in the range [first, last) in ascending order. *The order of equal elements is guaranteed to be preserved.*

with an appropriate comparison operator

```
std::stable_sort(vect.begin(), vect.end(),
     [](const std::pair<int, T> &x, const std::pair<int, T> &y) {
        return x.first < y.first;
     }
);
```